# colouring individual elements in a div

Tags: html, css

i'm in the process of writing my own website and have limited html / css experience so please go easy on me :)
i'm using the following html to give me a "menu" on the lhs of my webpage

and using the following css to align it to the left to allow another piece of header text to float on the rhs of this

```css
   .links {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0 5%;
    clear: left;
   }
   .links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
   }
   .links a:hover {
    background:lightblue;
   }
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="index.html"><b><i>Home</i></b></a>
  <a href="services.html"><b><i>Services</i></b></a>
  <a href="contact.html"><b><i>Contact Us</i></b></a>
 </div>
```

now, i'd really like to be able to colour an individual link boxes to show which page the user is on, but can't work out how
i've tried adding in extra "div's" for each link, but this throws the alignment off and puts the links under each other
any help would be greatly appreciated as i am keen to learn :)
many thanks

Comment: still not clear..what do you want to color...text..background..or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a individual class to a link like this:

```
<div class="links">
        <a class="clicked" href="index.html"><b><i>Home</i></b></a>
        <a href="services.html"><b><i>Services</i></b></a>
        <a href="contact.html"><b><i>Contact Us</i></b></a>
    </div>
```

Then style this class:

```
 .clicked{
        background: gray;
}
```

**I encourage you** to make navs using lists, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/o4tcsdmp/2/

Answer (score 1):

something like this..

Method1: Selecting by child position

```css
.links {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0 5%;
    clear: left;
}

.links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.links a:hover {
    background: lightblue;
}
div.links>a:nth-child(1){
 background-color:yellow;
 color:red;
}
div.links>a:nth-child(2){
 background-color:cyan;
 color:green;
}
div.links>a:nth-child(3){
 background-color:pink;
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <a href="index.html"><b><i>Home</i></b></a>
    <a href="services.html"><b><i>Services</i></b></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><b><i>Contact Us</i></b></a>
</div>
```

Method2: Selecting by specific attributes

```css
.links {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0 5%;
    clear: left;
}

.links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.links a:hover {
    background: lightblue;
}
a[href='index.html']{
 background-color:yellow;
 color:red;
}
a[href='services.html']{
 background-color:cyan;
 color:green;
}
a[href='contact.html']{
 background-color:pink;
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <a href="index.html"><b><i>Home</i></b></a>
    <a href="services.html"><b><i>Services</i></b></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><b><i>Contact Us</i></b></a>
</div>
```

`div>a:nth-child(3)` selects child of `div` which is `a` and only if its at 3rd position.

`a[href='services.html']` selects `a` element which have `href="services.html` attribute.

read more about [css selectors](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/)